# How can I get the Last Index of mysql that has been inserted to C# code behind?

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have a MySql stored procedure for inserting a row:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE AddPosition(
    IN strName VARCHAR(1000)
    ,IN strPositionType VARCHAR(1000)
    ,OUT intPositionId INT
)

BEGIN
INSERT INTO positions (
    positionName        
    , positionType

)
VALUES(
    strName
    ,strPositionType
);

SET intPositionId = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 


END
```

Honestly, I'm not really sure if this `SET intPositionId = LAST_INSERT_ID();` works, I want to get the value of IntPositionId and bring it to C#

in my c#;

```
public bool AddItem(Position data)
{
    int newId = 0;
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "AddPosition";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("strName", data.PositionName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("strPositionType", data.PositionType).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("intPositionId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    try
    {
        MyHelper.MyExecuteNonQuery(cmd);               

        newId = (int) cmd.Parameters["intPositionId"].Value; 
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `newId = (int) cmd.Parameters["intPositionId"].Value;` says "Specified cast is not valid."

when I tried to use debugging to find out what cmd.Parameters["intPositionId"].Value; returns,

[image]

it is just plain object with no value. I guess the `SET intPositionId = LAST_INSERT_ID();` didnt work.
so where did I go wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried int.TryParse instead?

Comment: the first thing I'd look at is: what is `cmd.Parameters["intPositionId"].Value` ? Assuming it isn't `null` (after the execute): what is `cmd.Parameters["intPositionId"].Value.GetType()`? is that `long` (`System.Int64`), for example? or `DbNull`? a cast from `object` to a primitive will only work for the right sized type

Comment: Check out the value inside `cmd.Parameters["intPositionId"].Value` by debugging. `InvalidCastException` occurs when value doesn't belong to proper data type, including `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: You should really do some debugging before you ask a question. With an `InvalidCastException`, the least you should do is to check the value you want to convert in the debugger.

Comment: i already did. i uploaded the screen shot

Comment: Have you actually checked the type of your value? Of course, that's **exactly** what's cut off in your picture, but I'm pretty sure it's `DBNull`. If that would be the case, your SP has returned NULL in the parameter and you are not taking that possibility into account.

Comment: What is the schema of your `positions` table? Does it have an `INT` (or `BIGINT`) `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key?